# Python 3. Return from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
videos = ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKI-tD0L18A',
           'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82LCKBdjywQ',
           'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GpNSip5gyKo]
```

I want to return it as a list, but with the easier form like: "youtu.be/(id) " instead of "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=(id)".

I hope you guys understand my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this list comprehension. It splits each url at the '=' sign to get the video id.

```
 shortvids = ['youtu.be/'+x.split('=')[1] for x in videos]
```

Result:

```
['youtu.be/oKI-tD0L18A', 'youtu.be/82LCKBdjywQ', 'youtu.be/GpNSip5gyKo']
```